# Woocommerce short description toggle on archive page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Im building shop on woocommerce and im trying to make spoiler under product with short description on archive page.
But unfortunetely it works only with first product.
I made changes inside content-product.php

```
<div class="tog-holder" id="tog">
  <div class="bar horizontal"></div>
  <div class="bar vertical"></div>
</div>
<div id="anim">
  <p><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ) ?></p>
</div>
```

Here is a css:

```
<style type="text/css">

  /* plus sign */
  #anim{display:none}
  .bar{transition:all .2s ease-in-out}
  #tog.animate .bar{-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg)}
  .tog-holder{position:relative;width:32px;height:32px;padding:15px 0}
  .bar{position:absolute;background-color:#000;}
  .horizontal {width:32px;height:2px;left:0;top:15px;}
  .vertical {width:2px;height:32px;left:15px;top:0}
</style>
```

And Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#tog").click(function() {
    jQuery("#tog").toggleClass("animate");
    jQuery("#anim").slideToggle(800);
  });
});
</script>
```

I think problem is with Jquery. I dont know it very well. I put script and css to to header with **Insert Headers and Footers plugin** it works like below on the screenshot.
Thanks in advance!

[image: How it looks right now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique identifiers and should only be existing once on a page.

Your jQuery script is getting the id "tog" and uses the click function. You are only do this for the first element with this id.

You should use a class instead and could use a for each to add this click function to all elements with this class.

Another method would be to add the on click to the html tag

```
<div onclick="yourFunction()"></div>
```

and create a function where you are referencing to "this" to always use THIS element which is clicked.

EDIT: Here is an example code for you, to make things clearer

```
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".class_of_your_hidden_description").hide();
            jQuery(".class_of_your_element_to_be_clicked").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).next(".class_of_your_hidden_description").slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
How to declare a function in JQuery? Cause i tried   $.fn.myfunction = function ()  {
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".anim").hide();
            jQuery(".tog-holder").click(function(){
                jQuery(this).next(".anim").slideToggle();
            });
        });
   } and it doesnt work at all..

Comment: If you use my script code snippet and adjust the classes in your markup and the script, you will be fine. The function is available when document is ready. With the click event, the toggle will only fire when the element is clicked. 
If you still want to have it in a named function an call it in the html onclick="", you can simply declare a normal Javascript function.

Comment: But i have another issue now. This plus should transform: rotate 45 deg when open and rotate again when closed. Is there any way to do it? Look at the screenshot above to make it clear.

Comment: You can add a class to your css where you make the transform and rotate the element. You will add this class to your "class_of_your_element_to_be_clicked", when it is clicked. So you simply add after the already existing ...... .click(function(){ jQuery(this).addClass('yourRotateClass'); 
jQuery(this).next ......